# Geocode was not successful for the following reason Zero result - PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, api, google-maps

I am trying to display the address which is called from
my sql database, I can't display the address I keep getting this error "Geocode was not successful for the following reason Zero_Results"

I tried to add the full address in one variable $address rather than using three variable  $address , $county , $county but still not 
working and I cannot figure it out.

I would like to display the address as marker as you can see in the image.

Whenever I added new address into my db I would get new marker added into the map.

[image]

Any help,

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code I am working with :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `test`") or die ("Error:      
 ".mysqli_error($con));
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
            $address = $row['address'];
            $county = $row['County'];
            $country = $row['Country'];
     }
        mysqli_close($con); 

        <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html>
          <head>

       <script type="text/javascript"
           src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?                       
           key=mykey&sensor=false">

        </script>


         <script type="text/javascript">
          var geocoder;
          var map;
          function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(          
            53.41291,-8.243889999999965);
            var address = '<?php echo $address.', '.$country.', '.$county; ?                 
          >';

            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 6,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),                  
             myOptions);
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results,    
              status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason:                    
               " + status);
              }
            });
          }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="initialize()">
          <div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:500px"></div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: What is the value of the address that is sent to the geocoder when you get "ZERO_RESULTS"?  (what does `'<?php echo $address.', '.$country.', '.$county; ?>';` resolve to?) It is probably not a geocodable address.

Comment: @geocodezip just full address like $address store Griffen Road and $county  stored Dublin and $country stored Ireland all are text type.

Comment: If I put "Griffen Road, Dublin,  Ireland" in [the example in the documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple), it works (doesn't return ZERO_RESULTS), so that isn't what your code is doing when it gets the reported error.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @geocodezip I know it works this way but doesn't work when I use it as PHP variable

Comment: @geocodezip how to solve this issue if I have a list of addresses stored in database ? Any examples or ideas

Comment: [second request] What is the value of `address` when you get "ZERO_RESULTS"?

Comment: @geocodezip I got the map but without marker of the address that i am trying recall from my db. I got alert message saying "Geocode was not successful for the following reason Zero result" wondering if there's another way for example I have a php file that generate all stored address in a xml format is there a way so i can call that php file and display them into the map as marker ? since this way not working for me.

Comment: [third request] What is the value of address when you get "ZERO_RESULTS"?

Comment: @geocodezip No result

Comment: I don't understand.  The `address` passed into the geocoder has no value?  That would explain "ZERO_RESULTS".

Comment: @geocodezip it should be location, I stored an address in $address which supposed to be displayed into map as marker.

Comment: I don't care what it _should_ be.  I want to know what it is.  I think if you could answer that question, the reason you are getting "ZERO_RESULTS" would be obvious.

Comment: @geocodezip    var address = '<?php echo $address.', '.$country.', '.$county; ?                 
          >';

Comment: I can read.  **What is the value of address in the browser; the code that produces that value on your system doesn't help me; it obviously (at least to me) isn't doing what you think it is**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem solved and my solution is :

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
            var geocoder;
            var map;
            function initialize(address) {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(   
              53.41291,-8.243889999999965);


            var myOptions = {
              zoom: 6,
              center: latlng,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),            
            myOptions);
            <?php
            require('connection.php');

              $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `test`") or die  
                ("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
              $count = 0;


            ?>
            <?php  //Starts while loop so all addresses for the given 
                // information will be populated.
             $addresscounting=0;
               while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) //instantiates 
                 // array
           { ?>   


             var address = "<?php echo $address ?>";


            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results,                 
             status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason:             
             " + status);
              }
            });

         <?php
               $count++;

              } //ends while
          ?>
          }

          </script
```

Comment: Sooo what did you change?